# How put repeat jobs in pgAgent

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I have several data sources and create a C# app to connect to each one, download the data and insert into postgres.

That create a Data Pool and I create a Timer Event to execute a store procedure to process that pool in batch of 800.

The problem is sometimes the 800 batch give me a time out. So I want change that from C# timer to pgAgent.

I have configure pgAgent before, but not sure how will work on this case.

Lets say I set the pgAgent to execute `process` every min

- check for the unprocess rows, select 100 and start the process.
- but if after one min the process hasnt end it, pgAgent will start again and see the same 100 rows unprocessed.
- Also the process need to be sequential, I cant start rows 100 to 200 until first 100 are done.
- Finally if process end In more than one minute and still data in the pool, the process should start again and not wait for the pgAgent timer.

In C# I just create a thread and if after the timer run off the process is still busy I just wait for another minute.

So can I configure pgAgent to handle this scenerio?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you tried, you already found the answer to your question.  But pgAgent will wait until the previous run is complete to start the next run of the same job.